# Use synthetic division to find the quotient and remainder when:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use synthetic division to find the quotient and remainder when: $P(x)=x^4-3x^3+3x^2+2x-1$ Is divided by $x-4$?

Comment: Could someone please explain synthetic division to me? Along with how to find the quotient and remainder.

Comment: Use a video on YouTube (like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc_EWcTfiC4) and try solving it yourself. If you don't succeed, come back and I will help you.

Comment: Ok, I used the way the video showed me, it was easier to understand and I got the remainder of 119. But now I'm confused on how to find the quotient..

Comment: The remainder of 119 is right. Now what numbers did you write on the left of your remainder?

Comment: 30, 7, 1, 1 in that order

Comment: Alright, your synthetic division table is correct! Now look at my post and you'll see how to handle it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

119 represents the remainder, and $x^3+x^2+7x+30$ represents the quotient.

Comment: So to find the quotient I just replace the numbers in the original polynomial with the numbers left of the remainder?

Comment: No, you read from right to left all the numbers below the line, and you increase the power of x by beginning with the number left to the remainder, so $30x^0+7x^1+1x^2+1x^3=x^3+x^2+7x+30$.

Comment: Oh! Ok, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Always try to make the highest degree term of the dividend 0.
Firstly, when you divide $P(x)=x^4-3x^3+3x^2+2x-1$ by $x-4$, try to make $x^4$ term 0. 
Thus, you'll multiply $x-4$ by $x^3$ and subtract from the dividend. This gives a quotient of $x^3$ and remainder of $x^3+3x^2+2x-1$.

Now, go on like this till the degree of your remainder is less than that of your divisor.

The final answer would be : Quotient = $x^3 + x^2+7*x +30$ and Remainder = 119.

(Try working it out by yourself! )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start: It is essentially like regular long division but with polynomials!

$$ (x-4) | x^4-3x^3+3x^2+2x-1 $$ The first term to go on top is $x^3$, since that gives   $x^4$, then $-4 \cdot x^3$ gives $-4x^3$. So write $x^4-4x^3$ underneath the polynomial. Subtract and repeat the process.